# My website sends mail ,gmail, locally but not on server. Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

The following is the send_mail() model function that I use to send emails using the 'email', 'subject', and 'content' of message. Locally the website sends emails through gmail perfectly yet, on the hosting server it gives me an SMTP error: 
    unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com .

```
function send_mail( $mail, $subject, $msg )
      {
            $receiver  = $mail;
            $title = $subject;
            $sender  = "Dina";
            $sender_mail = "myemail@gmail.com";
            $message = '<html><body>';
            //$message .= "Hey $mail,<br><br>";
            $message .= $msg;
            $message .= "</body></html>";
            $ci = get_instance();
            $ci->load->library('email');
            $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
            $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
            $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
            $config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@gmail.com";
            $config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
            $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
            $config['mailtype'] = "html";
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
            $ci->email->initialize($config);

            $ci->email->from($sender_mail, $sender);
            $list = array($receiver);
            $ci->email->to($list);
            $this->email->reply_to('myemail@gmail.com', 'Dina');
            $ci->email->subject($title);
            $ci->email->message($message);
            // $ci->email->send();
            if(!$ci->email->send())
            {
               $this->email->print_debugger();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, it still works locally just fine with that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the hosting company forbids these ports on their firewall, might you should ask them.

Comment: I think this more suited as a comment.